# Why does modern F1 sound like a lawn mower?

Tags: formula-1

Why do modern F1 cars sound like a strained 1.6 liter Honda from a low-end family sedan?

Comment: Welcome to Sports Stack Exchange. We expect answers to be posted as answers, and generally to avoid commenting on a post within that post itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2014, Formula One switched from 2.4L V8 engines to 1.6L V6 "turbo-hybrid" engines. This change was made primarily to improve fuel efficiency, reduce emissions, and make the sport's technology more relevant to road cars (there are now very few car companies, if any, that don't produce hybrids).

The sound of the turbo-hybrid V6s, compared to the V8s and V10s of yesteryear, has been criticised ever since they were introduced. As you alluded to in your question, many believe they're not loud enough, and prefer the distinctive high-pitched scream that the V10s had. The FIA [plan to address this criticism](https://www.thedrive.com/news/actually-f1-engines-will-get-louder-in-2021-domenicali-says) when the engine formula changes in 2026 - while the engines will remain 1.6L V6 turbo-hybrids, they will be made louder than they are now.